# Angular how to show page on other page as router

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a starter project for me. What i need to do is create a component in which i call navbar, sidebar, footer and a page that i want to show as router.

This is my app.routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './screens/auth/login/login.component';
import { StatsComponent } from './screens/stats/stats.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'Dashboard', component: LayoutComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'stats', component: StatsComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I have a simple login page by which i go to dashboard rout

```
<h1>Angular Router App</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/Dashboard/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my LayoutComponent (Dashboard)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="app-sidebar" data-active-color="white" data-background-color="black" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-bg/01.jpg">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
         <div class="sidebar-background"></div>
     </div>
     <!-- <app-navbar></app-navbar> -->
     <p>NavBar</p>
     <div class="main-panel">   
         <div class="main-content">
             <div class="content-wrapper">
                 <div class="container-fluid">
                     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <!-- <app-footer></app-footer> -->
         <p>Footer</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

You can see I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on this page this I need to know how can I show another component in this? I have a component `stats` on app-routing. Do I need to show that component inside this layout how can I show this as routing?

Mean something like `Dashboard/stats`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use routing in a project you should create the project as follows:

```
ng new my-project --routing=true
```

This will create a routing file that you will need, namely `app-routing.module.ts`

Now to create a route:

```
ng generate module routes/route-1 --routing=true
```

This will create new files, in particular:

`route-1.module.ts`
`route-1-routing.module.ts`

In `route-1-routing.module.ts` define routes like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Route1Component },
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent }
]
```

(obviously create these components with something like `ng g c routes/route-1/components/route-1` and `ng g c routes/route-1/components/hello` - these commands are executed on the command line, just like when you use the ng new command)

Now back in app-routing.module.ts add this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'route-1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/route-1/route-1.module').then(m => m.Route1Module)
  }
]
```

now you can visit:

`/route-1` in your browser and you will see Route1Component (where `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is - don't forget to add `router-outlet` in app.component.html)

and you can visit:

`/route-1/hello` in your browser and you will see HelloComponent (again where `router-outlet` is)

Finally, you can create links to your route using

```
<a routerLink="/route-1">route-1</a>
<a routerLink="/route-1/hello">route-1/hello</a>
```

Repeat this process to add more routes.

Much love in Him :D

Comment: Yes, it's showing that route but it's not showing sidebar navbar things. Mean my route-1.html look like this <h1>Layout</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> When I go to /route-1 its shows Layout which is correct and when I go to /route-1/hello it's showing Hello works but it needs to show Layout and Hello works both.

Comment: you should put router-outlet in app.component.html not within a route! (unless you have routes within routes)